# Unwanted Vertical Space after Header

Tags: spacing, minipage, vertical, vspace, header

I have created a custom header that's perfect except for some unwanted vertical spacing between the header and the body. Currently there's about 14mm of spacing, and I'd like to reduce it to about 7mm. Nothing I've tried has reduced the spacing: I've tried `vspace{-7mm}` in various places, and I've tried to adjust the height of the minipage, but to no avail. My code is below along with a picture of the output.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=2cm,headheight=50pt,headsep=0pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb,amscd,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{lastpage, enumerate, fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\raggedbottom
%\usepackage{showframe}

\renewcommand\maketitlehooka{%

    \vspace{-10cm}
    \begin{minipage}[t][10cm][b]{\textwidth}
        \begin{minipage}{.35\textwidth}
            Calculus II --- Quiz 8 \\ November 24, 2019
        \end{minipage}%
        \begin{minipage}{.65\textwidth}
             \raggedleft
              \vspace{5mm} Full Name: \underline{\hspace{4cm}} 
        \end{minipage}%
        \vspace{2mm}
        \line(1,0){500}
        \textit{ Answer all of the following problems. You must \textbf{show all of your work} to receive full credit. This quiz is worth 10 points. } 
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[b][0cm][b]{\textwidth}
        \author{} %leave empty
        \date{} %leave empty
        \title{} %leave empty
        \vspace{-1cm}
    \end{minipage}

}


\begin{document}

\maketitle
\vspace{-3.5cm}
1) I would like the vertical space between this line and \enquote{This quiz is worth 10 points} to be about half the amount it currently is.


\end{document}
```

[image: Here's a picture]

Comment: what is the second minipage for?  I would not bother doing this as a titlepage section.  Why don't you just put the minipage you like on the page?

Comment: @ Thruston: I should have ommitted that; it was left over from one of my attempts to reduce the spacing.

Comment: @siracusa: I tried changing the value of ```headheight``` to 0pt and also tried making it negative, but there was no change in the spacing whatsoever :(

Comment: Problem solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use the `fancyhdr` package to your advantage? To change the spacing between the last line of the italic header and the first line of the actual text, change the value of `headsep` to your liking.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\usepackage[top=4.25cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=2cm,headheight=65pt,headsep=15pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb,amscd,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{lastpage, enumerate, fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tabularx,calc,booktabs} %<----- added
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\raggedbottom
%\usepackage{showframe}

\lhead{\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}l>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X@{}}
       Calculus II --- Quiz 8 \\ 
       November 24, 2019  &  Full Name: \underline{\hspace{4cm}}\\
       \midrule
       \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}{\textit{Answer all of the following problems. You must \textbf{show all of your work} to receive full credit. This quiz is worth 10 points.}}
       \end{tabularx}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}


\pagestyle{fancy}



\begin{document}

1) I would like the vertical space between this line and \enquote{This quiz is worth 10 points} to be about half the amount it currently is.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I am trying to avoid using ```fancyhdr``` because I want to potentially have multiple pages in the document without any header on the following pages. Essentially, I want the header just like you've made it, but only on the first page, with no headers on successive pages. Thanks.

Comment: In that case, just place the tabularx wherever you want to use it in your document.

Comment: Thank you, I removed the ```lhead{``` part and put the ```tabularx``` block after ```begin{document}``` and it looks perfect!

Answer (score 2):

Remove the last (empty) minipage and use `\maketitlehookd`. Unrelated: I took to opportunity to simplify a bit your preamble.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\usepackage[margin=2cm, headheight=50pt, headsep=0pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, amscd, mathrsfs}
\usepackage{lastpage, enumerate, fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\raggedbottom
%\usepackage{showframe}

   \setlength{\droptitle}{-10cm}%
\renewcommand\maketitlehooka{%
    \begin{minipage}[t][10cm][b]{\textwidth}
        \begin{minipage}{.35\textwidth}
            Calculus II --- Quiz 8 \\ November 24, 2019
        \end{minipage}%
        \begin{minipage}{.65\textwidth}
             \raggedleft
              \vspace{5mm} Full Name: \underline{\hspace{4cm}}
        \end{minipage}%
        \vspace{2mm}
        \line(1,0){500}
        \textit{ Answer all of the following problems. You must \textbf{show all of your work} to receive full credit. This quiz is worth 10 points. }
    \end{minipage}
}
 \author{} %leave empty
 \date{} %leave empty
 \title{} %leave empty
\renewcommand{\maketitlehookd}{\vspace{-7\baselineskip}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

1) I would like the vertical space between this line and \enquote{This quiz is worth 10 points} to be about half the amount it currently is.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this alternative solution.